# How to convert SQL subquery to Linq

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq

I have two tables, `Employees` and `Transactions`.

First table: `dbo.Employees`

[image]

Second table: `dbo.Transactions`

[image]

I need to convert the below query to a lambda expression (Linq):

```
SELECT Employees.EmployeeId, Trans.LastTrans
FROM dbo.Employees
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT EmployeeId, MAX(TrasactionDate) LastTrans 
     FROM dbo.Transactions 
     GROUP BY EmployeeId) Trans ON Trans.EmployeeId = Employees.EmployeeId
```

I want the result `employeeId` and `LastTrans` as shown below:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

See following.  The query does not need two Select in linq :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;


namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Context db = new Context()
            {
                Employees = new List<Employees>() {
                    new Employees() { EmployeeId = 1, Name = "Hossam"},
                    new Employees() { EmployeeId = 2, Name = "Peter"},
                    new Employees() { EmployeeId = 3, Name = "George"}
                },
                Transactions = new List<Transactions>() {
                    new Transactions() { TranactionId = 1, amount = 200, TransactionDate = DateTime.Parse("2020-01-02"), EmployeeId = 1},
                    new Transactions() { TranactionId = 2, amount = 300, TransactionDate = DateTime.Parse("2020-02-02"), EmployeeId = 1},
                    new Transactions() { TranactionId = 3, amount = 1000, TransactionDate = DateTime.Parse("2020-02-25"), EmployeeId = 1},
                    new Transactions() { TranactionId = 4, amount = 5000, TransactionDate = DateTime.Parse("2020-04-01"), EmployeeId = 2},
                    new Transactions() { TranactionId = 5, amount = 7000, TransactionDate = DateTime.Parse("2020-07-16"), EmployeeId = 2},
                    new Transactions() { TranactionId = 6, amount = 8000, TransactionDate = DateTime.Parse("2020-08-06"), EmployeeId = 3},
                    new Transactions() { TranactionId = 6, amount = 600, TransactionDate = DateTime.Parse("2020-09-04"), EmployeeId = 3}
                }
            };
            var results = (from trans in db.Transactions
                           join emp in db.Employees on trans.EmployeeId equals emp.EmployeeId
                           select new { EmployeeId = trans.EmployeeId, LastTrans = trans.TransactionDate }
                           ).GroupBy(x => x.EmployeeId)
                           .Select(x => x.OrderByDescending(y => y.LastTrans))
                           .Select(x => x.First())
                           .OrderBy(x => x.EmployeeId)
                           .ToList();
        }
    }
    public class Context
    {
        public List<Employees> Employees { get; set; }
        public List<Transactions> Transactions { get; set; }
    }
    public class Employees
    {
        public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
    public class Transactions
    {
        public int TranactionId { get; set; }
        public decimal amount { get; set; }
        public DateTime TransactionDate { get; set; }
        public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: I updated code to change where the OrderBy date was done which is a little more efficient because you sort only needed items.  The Join is eliminating the employees that are not in the Employee table (not obvious) so original method was sort the employee that are not used.  The join is not need when there are employees in the Transaction Table and not in the Employee Table.  If you have a company with departments and the Employee Table is for one departments than the new code run quicker.

Answer (score 0):

This query is enough to get your result and you do not need additional join to Employees

```
var grouped = 
  from trans in db.Transactions
  group trans by trans.EmployeeId into g
  select new 
  { 
      EmployeeId = g.Key,
      LastTrans = g.Max(x => x.TrasactionDate)
  };
```